# Simulate key stroke in any application

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-hook

How do I simulate a key stroke in a window that is not my C# application ?

Right now i'm using `SendKeys.Send()` but it does not work. The thing is I have a global keyboard hook so I catch the input directly from the keyboard and `SendKeys.Send()` is not seen like a real keyboard stroke.

The best would be to simulate a real keystroke this way, no matter what is the application i'm in, my program will catch it as if someone pressed a key.

I guess I found part of the problem. This is the event called if a key is pressed :

```
static void KeyBoardHook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
   // Writes the pressed key in the console (it works)
   Console.WriteLine(e.KeyCode.ToString());

   // Check if pressed key is Up Arrow (it works and enters the condition)
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
   {
     // Send the key again. (does not work)
     SendKeys.Send("{UP}");
   } 
}
```

I tried it this way to :

```
static void KeyBoardHook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
   // Writes the pressed key in the console (it works)
   Console.WriteLine(e.KeyCode.ToString());

   // Check if pressed key is Up Arrow (it works and enters the condition)
   if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
   {
     // Send the key again. (does not work)
     PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle,WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP,0);
   } 
}
```

but it does not work either. The thing is since I send the key inside my event, will it call itself because a key has been pressed ? In case someone needs it, the code above.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string args)
{
  KeyBoardHook.CreateHook();
  KeyBoardHook.KeyPressed += KeyBoardHook_KeyPressed;
  Application.Run();
  KeyBoardHook.Dispose();
}
```

if you need the `KeyBoardHook` class I can post it too.

My guess is that my keyboard hook is catching the low-level keyboard outputs and the `SendKeys` is just simulating a keystroke so my hook doesn't catch it. Anybody thinks of a work around ?

Comment: Check that cool Windows Input Simulator library here: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ (not posting this as an answer as there are cursed diamond moderators deleting around these days)

Comment: @SimonMourier why would they be deleting it ?

Comment: Because links (when there is not text around) are not allowed in answers (which applied blindly is - I think - stupid). See SO's faq for more.

Comment: Too bad because its exactly what im looking for. Try putting some words around it and post the link below so I can accept it :P

Comment: @Simon: As long as your answer has enough explanation in it that people (1) know whether it's useful without following the link and (2) have something to search for if the link breaks, it should be safe from deletion.

Comment: @ben voight - Although I understand the idea behind this faq chapter, I believe some links, even simple, are useful, and can't easily be quoted. I had a +3 answer deleted lately with a link that answered much more than the other answers. We poor SO standard citizens are just terrorized by the diamond guys. Afraid to answer. Afraid to violate the faq. Afraid to go on Meta to get beaten up more.

Comment: @Simon: If you did what I just said (explained why the resource is useful, and included enough information to find the resource again if the link broke), which you did a great job of here, then I'll have your back when it comes to discussions with diamond mods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use this very cool library that masks all the complexity for you, the Windows Input Simulator available here: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

I believe it's based on the Windows' [SendInput function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can p/invoke the `keybd_event` (which is much simpler and easier) or `SendInput` (which is newer and has more capabilities) functions, which simulate keyboard input at a much lower level.

Comment: So with SendInput, my hook should catch it ? even if the SendInput is Inside the KeyPressedEvent ??

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: If you call `SendInput` inside the hook, you'll probably end up with infinite recursion.

Comment: true. the thing is it will be called only if it meets a certain condition